# Uniqueness of the nodes for Gauss-Legendre quadrature

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Gauss-Legendre quadrature approximates $\int_{~1}^{1}f(x)dx$ by $\sum_{i=1}^nw_if(x_i)$.

Wikipedia says that

> This choice of quadrature weights $w_i$ and quadrature nodes $x_i$ is the unique choice that allows the quadrature rule to integrate degree $2n − 1$ polynomials exactly.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Legendre_quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature)

The uniqueness of $w_i$ satisfying the condition for fixed $x_i$ comes from the invertibility of the Vandermonde's matrix.

How to prove the uniqueness of $x_i$?

Comment: A side remark: See this very interesting article by the famous numerical analyst L. Trefethen : https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/exactnessRev2.pdf where (page 2) he says: " in most textbooks, it is implied that the main advantage of Gauss over Newton–
Cotes is that it has exactness degree $2n − 1$. This is highly misleading. Gauss quadrature is indeed better than Newton–Cotes, but the main reason is not its doubled degree of exactness. [ctd]"

Comment: Fix $n$ distinct points in the interval $[-1,1]. $ Then there are unique weights so that the quadrature formula holds for the polynomials of degree less or equal $n.$ But if we want to get the formula true for the polynomials of degree $2n-1$ the nodes should be specific, coincide with the roots of the Legendre polynomial of degree  $n.$

Comment: In fact, equidistant nodes have their issues. If we interpolate a polynomial using equidistant nodes, the resulting polynomial usually highly oscillates (Runges phenomenon). With Tchebycheff ot Legendre polynomials this can be avoided, this explains why such choices of nodes are better for numerical integration as well. But that a higer degree increases the precision is not actually wrong. This is true even for Newton-Cotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that there are nodes $x_1<x_2<\ldots < x_n$ and the weights $w_i>0$ such that
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1p(x)\,dx =\sum_{i=1}^n w_ip(x_i),\qquad \deg p\le 2n-1$$
Assume
there are other nodes $x_1'<x_2'<\ldots <x_n'$ and quantities $w_i'$ (not necessarily nonnegative) such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n w_ip(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n w_i'p(x_i'),\qquad \deg p\le 2n-1\quad (*)$$

Assume there exists a polynomial $q,$  $\deg q\le 2n-1,$ $q(x_i)\ge 0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n$  and
$q(x)=0$ iff $x\in \{x_1',x_2',\ldots, x_n'\}.$
Then the formula $(*)$ implies $q(x_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n.$ Therefore $x_i'=x_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n.$

Now we are going to construct a polynomial $q$ with the properties described above. Assume one of the intervals $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ contains more than one element of $\{x_j'\}_{j=1}^n$
$$x_k\le x'_{l} <x'_{l+1}\le x_{k+1}$$
Then
$$q(x)=(x-x'_l)(x-x'_{l+1})\prod_{j\neq l,l+1}^n(x-x'_j)^2$$
In the opposite case every interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ contains at most one element $x_j'.$ By the pigeonhole principle either $x_1'<x_1$ or $x_n'>x_n.$
In the first case let
$$q(x)=(x-x_1')\prod_{j=2}^n(x-x'_j)^2$$ and in the second case
$$q(x)=(x_n'-x)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(x-x'_j)^2$$
In all three cases we have $\deg q\le 2n-1,$ $q(x_i')=0$ and $q(x_i)\ge 0.$